# TCP сокет клиент сильно отстает в принятии байт от QTcpSocket сервера

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qt5

Я передаю файл с ПК-сервера, написанном на Qt, на андроид-клиент. Первые пару пакетов байт клиент принимает нормально. А потом начинается адское отставание от сервера. Т.е. в клиенте почти все время `in.available() == 0`.
Раньше такого дикого отставания не было, код вроде был такой же. `flush` возвращает `true`, а клиент висит в цикле с `available=0`.
Скорость интернета на клиенте вроде такая же как и на ПК, даже больше.

Отправка файла кратко:

```
int len = file.size();
int writingBytes0 = 0;
if (len > 8192) {
    while (1) { 
        QByteArray b = file.read(8192);
        if (b.isEmpty()) {
            pClientSocket->flush();
            break;
        }
        pClientSocket->write(b);
        bool fl = pClientSocket->flush();          
        writingBytes0 += b.size();
        mw->setPrUn(writingBytes0);
    }
} else {
    QByteArray b = file.read(len);
    //stream->writeRawData(b, b.size());
    pClientSocket->write(b);
    mw->setPrUn(len);
    pClientSocket->flush();
}
file.close();
```

Код принятия файла на клиенте:

```
long msize = file.length();
long writebites = 0;
long writebites0 = msize;
while (msize != writebites) {
    int avaibl = in.available();
    if (avaibl > 0) { //вот тут отставание, и очень сильное
        if (avaibl < writebites0) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[avaibl];
            in.read(buf);
            writebites = writebites + avaibl;
            fos.write(buf);
            writebites0 = writebites0 - avaibl;
        } else {
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int)msize];
            in.read(buf);
            writebites = msize;
            fos.write(buf);
            writebites0 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы для начала запустил бы wireshark  и посмотрел.  И что такое "адское отставание"? секунда? минута? сутки?

Comment: Приблизительно секунда.

Comment: меня очень сильно смущает этот бесконечный цикл. Он случайно не в главном потоке запущен?

Comment: В Qt да, я потом уже думал в отдельный поток переносить, работало то.

Comment: просто если это все крутится в главном треде, то блокируется eventloop со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: Да попробую в отдельном потоке запустить все странно вроде все работало.

Comment: Вы в цикле постоянно дергаете сокет и  в результате Ваше приложение только тем и занимается, что ганяет цикл в холостую. Напишите нормально, через сигналы-слоты и будет все ок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенос в отдельный поток мне не помог, помогло то что я вместо

```
pClientSocket->flush();
```

стал использовать

```
pClientSocket->waitForBytesWritten();
```

В принципе в документации его сам trolltech советует использовать. Правда медленее отгружает, но отставания в клиенте нету.